# How to access asp.net property in javaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm trying this code to access a property but it gives me an error:

```
<textarea class="<%#Eval("soort").ToString() %>" ID="TextTranslation" runat="server" rows="5"><%#Eval("Translation") %></textarea>
```

The error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>   Parser Error
>   Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.
>
> Parser Error Message: The server tag is not well formed.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 17:         
>   Line 18:         <%# (Eval("IsoCode").ToString() != Eval("Default").ToString()) ? " hidden" : "" %>">
>   Line 19:             " ID="TextTranslation" runat="server" rows="5"><%#Eval("Translation") %>
>   Line 20:         
>   Line 21:
>
> Source File: /assets/usercontrols/TranslationControl.ascx    Line: 19
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET  Version:4.0.30319.272

Comment: This is a server tag. You should set its properties in your code, not in the markup. You can try removing runat="server" if it was unintentional.

Comment: Check your quotes: class='<%#Eval("soort").ToString() %>'

Comment: Could be the solution, but I don't work in the project anymore. Should I close this question?

Comment: That's the answer @MikaelHärsjö, post it to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your quotes to: class='<%#Eval("soort").ToString() %>'